# Advanced search features

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search

First it would be nice to search through the questions I've asked on SO to find a particular question.

Second, it would also be nice if the main search function at the top of the page had an "advanced search" option whereby you could specify things like tags and whether you're looking for answers or questions or both and perhaps specify a date-range.

Comment: You can do almost all of those things. See the advanced search options page http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do almost all of those things. See the [advanced search options page.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/searching)