# What are the list of functions we can use to search in the bar above?

Tags: support, search

I could not find this anywhere. But can someone list the functions available to use in the search above.

Example this:

```
[discussion] //it searches for questions with discussion tag
[discussion] or [comments] //either that or this
[discussion] and [comments] //both tags
```

What else is there?

Comment: Is this what you're after: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78695/217863 ?

Comment: For both tags, it's just `[discussion] [comments]` (without the `and`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've given a pretty thorough answer to this [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9332/31394) for SFF, and the same tricks work on all SE sites. The info comes from the [Advanced Search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching) page in the help centre, which is linked on the sidebar of [any search results page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search). Happy reading!

Comment: I think a link-only answer is acceptable when the link is *within SE* :-)

Comment: I was under the impression that link-only answers are discouraged no matter where the link points to. Side note: duplicating these questions on every other Meta post doesn't seem constructive, it seems best to keep Meta posts that aren't specific to any site on one site: this one.

Comment: @Dukeling AFAIK, the rationale for discouraging link-only answers is that the link might go dead if the other site goes down. If SE goes down, this doesn't matter anyway, and if SE moves a load of its links, then links to them will probably be auto-edited (like MSO -> MSE). Also, answering an SE-wide question on a per-site meta **is** often useful, because people ask it there who don't visit or don't know about MSE. When I made that meta.SFF FAQ post about search, I had to close **six** older questions as dupes of it. People do ask about this stuff on per-site metas.